# TensorFlow: Does it only have SGD algorithms? or does it also have others like LBFGS

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, data-science

Question about TensorFlow:

I was looking at the video and model on the site, and it appeared to only have SGD as an algorithm for machine learning. I was wondering if other algorithms are also included in tensorflow, such as L-BFGS.

Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TensorFlow's jargon for the algorithms such as Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD) is optimizer. Following are the optimizers supported by TensorFlow:

- [GradientDescentOptimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/train.html#GradientDescentOptimizer)
- [AdadeltaOptimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/train.html#AdadeltaOptimizer)
- [AdagradOptimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/train.html#AdagradOptimizer)
- [AdamOptimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/train.html#AdamOptimizer)
- [FtrlOptimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/train.html#FtrlOptimizer)
- [MomentumOptimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/train.html#MomentumOptimizer)
- [RMSPropOptimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/train.html#RMSPropOptimizer)

You can also use the [TensorFlow SciPy Optimizer interface](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/opt/ScipyOptimizerInterface) which gives you access to optimizers like the L-BFGS.

Further, [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/train) and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/opt) are all the available TensorFlow optimizers you could use.